# OpenSSL types.h errors on compiling

Tags: c, openssl

I'm trying to make a password recover tool for Chrome in C, but getting there errors:

```
$ ./build.bat
In file included from C:\...\main.c:6:
C:\...\libs\openssl\types.h:166:29: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
  166 | typedef struct X509_name_st X509_NAME;
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~
C:\...\libs\openssl\types.h:207:33: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
  207 | typedef struct ocsp_response_st OCSP_RESPONSE;
```

I got this working somehow a year or 2 ago, but now I don't seem to get it to work.

(there is also some problem that it returns to some of the passwords extra letters or too few letters, but to some it brings the right one, this is likely a problem I made with the memory stuff)

Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
// Part 1: Decrypt Secret Key
#include <openssl/evp.h>
// Step 3: Find Folders.
#include <regex.h>
// Step 4: Connect to the database file.
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <jansson.h>
// Step 5: Decrypt the password!
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
char chrome_path[1024];
char local_state_path[1024];
char chrome_path_login_db[256];
char temp_path[1024];
DWORD master_length;
unsigned char* AESkey;

void handleErrors(void) {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    exit(1);
}
char **getFolders(char *chrome_path, int *num_folders) {
    // Open the directory at CHROME_PATH
    DIR *dir = opendir(chrome_path);
    if (dir == NULL) {
        printf("Error: could not open directory '%s'\n", chrome_path);
        *num_folders = 0;
        exit(1);
    }

    // Regex to find file I guess, I forgor
    regex_t regex;
    int ret = regcomp(&regex, "^Profile*|^Default$", REG_EXTENDED);
    if (ret != 0) {
        closedir(dir);
        *num_folders = 0;
        exit(1);
    }
    struct dirent *entry;
    int count = 0;
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (regexec(&regex, entry->d_name, 0, NULL, 0) == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    *num_folders = count;
    char **folders = malloc(count * sizeof(char *));
    if (folders == NULL) {
        printf("Error: could not allocate memory\n");
        regfree(&regex);
        closedir(dir);
        *num_folders = 0;
        exit(1);
    }
    rewinddir(dir);
    count = 0;
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (regexec(&regex, entry->d_name, 0, NULL, 0) == 0) {
            size_t len = strlen(entry->d_name) + 1;
            folders[count] = malloc(len);
            if (folders[count] == NULL) {
                printf("Error: could not allocate memory\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    free(folders[i]);
                }
                free(folders);
                regfree(&regex);
                closedir(dir);
                *num_folders = 0;
                exit(1);
            }
            strncpy(folders[count], entry->d_name, len);
            count++;
        }
    }
    regfree(&regex);
    closedir(dir);
    return folders;
}
sqlite3* main_sqlite_password_dumper(const char* db_file) {
    sqlite3* db;
    int rc = sqlite3_open_v2(db_file, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY, NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        exit(1);
    }
    sqlite3_busy_timeout(db, 500);
    const char* query = "SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins;";
    sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error preparing statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        const unsigned char* url = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
        const unsigned char* username = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1);
        const unsigned char* password = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2);
        if (url != NULL && username != NULL && password != NULL && strlen(url) > 5 && strlen(url) != 0 && strlen(username) != 0 && strlen(password) != 0) {
            printf("\033[0;33m");
            printf("**********************************************************\n\n");
            printf("\033[0;36mUsername:   \033[0;32m%s\n", username);
            printf("\033[0;36mURL:   \033[0;32m%s\n", url);
            // Setup The Variables & other stuff for the decryption process
            uint8_t buffer[1096] = { 0 };
            uint8_t key[32];
            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
                key[i] = (uint8_t) AESkey[i];
            }
            size_t password_len = strlen(password);
            uint8_t ciphertext[password_len];
            for (int i = 0; i < password_len; i++) {
                ciphertext[i] = (uint8_t) password[i];
            }
            // Decrypt!
            char *encrypted_password = malloc(strlen(ciphertext) - 15 - 16 + 1); // allocate memory for the substring
            int output_length = strlen(password) - 30 - 1;
            if (encrypted_password != NULL) {
                strncpy(encrypted_password, ciphertext + 15, strlen(ciphertext) - 15 - 16); // copy the substring
                encrypted_password[strlen(ciphertext) - 15 - 16] = '\0'; // add null terminator
            }
            int decrypted_len = gcm_decrypt(&ciphertext[15], 13, NULL, 0, &ciphertext[21], key, &ciphertext[3], 12, buffer);
            SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
            printf("\033[0;36mDecrypted password: \033[0;32m%.*s\n\n", output_length, buffer);

        }
    }
    printf("\033[0;33m");
    printf("**********************************************************\n");
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return db;
}
int gcm_decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len,
                unsigned char *aad, int aad_len,
                unsigned char *tag,
                unsigned char *key,
                unsigned char *iv, int iv_len,
                unsigned char *plaintext) {
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len;
    int plaintext_len;
    int ret;
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();
    if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL))
        handleErrors();
    if(!EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, iv_len, NULL))
        handleErrors();
    if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();
    if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, NULL, &len, aad, aad_len))
        handleErrors();
    if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len = len;
    if(!EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG, 16, tag))
        handleErrors();
    ret = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    if(ret > 0) {
        plaintext_len += len;
        return plaintext_len;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
const char* secretKey() {
    char* key;
    char* encrypted_key = NULL;
    FILE* file = fopen(local_state_path, "r");
    static char buffer[4096];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file)) {
        char* ptr = strstr(buffer, "\"encrypted_key\":\"");
        if (ptr) {
            ptr += strlen("\"encrypted_key\":\"");
            char* end = strchr(ptr, '\"');
            if (end) {
                size_t len = end - ptr;
                encrypted_key = malloc(len + 1);
                strncpy(encrypted_key, ptr, len);
                encrypted_key[len] = '\0';
                key = encrypted_key;
                fclose(file);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    int inlen = strlen(key);
    int outlen = (inlen * 3) / 4 + 5;
    unsigned char* inbuf = (unsigned char*)key;
    unsigned char* outbuf = malloc(outlen);
    memset(outbuf, 0, outlen);
    EVP_DecodeBlock(outbuf, inbuf, inlen);
    unsigned char b64d[outlen];
    memset(b64d, 0, outlen);
    for (int i = 0; i < outlen - 5; i++) {
        b64d[i] = outbuf[i+5];
    }
    DATA_BLOB input;
    input.cbData = outlen - 5;
    input.pbData = b64d;
    DATA_BLOB output;
    CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT promptStruct;
    promptStruct.cbSize = sizeof(CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT);
    promptStruct.dwPromptFlags = CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPT_ON_UNPROTECT;
    promptStruct.hwndApp = NULL;
    promptStruct.szPrompt = NULL;
    DWORD flags = CRYPTPROTECT_UI_FORBIDDEN | CRYPTPROTECT_VERIFY_PROTECTION;
    if (CryptUnprotectData(
            &input,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &promptStruct,
            flags,
            &output)) {
        unsigned char* secret_key = malloc(output.cbData);
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < output.cbData; i++) {
            secret_key[i] = output.pbData[i];
        }
        master_length = output.cbData;
        LocalFree(output.pbData);
        return secret_key;
    } else {
        exit(1);
    }
    free(outbuf);
}
int main() {
    // Setup some variables.
    char* userprofile = getenv("USERPROFILE");
    snprintf(local_state_path, sizeof(local_state_path), "%s\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Local State", userprofile);
    snprintf(chrome_path, sizeof(chrome_path), "%s\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data", userprofile);
    snprintf(temp_path, sizeof(temp_path), "%s\\AppData\\Local\\Temp", userprofile);

    // Get the secret key from the function.
    AESkey = secretKey();

    // Confirm the folder with the getFolders function.
    int num_folders;
    char **folders = getFolders(chrome_path, &num_folders);
    if (folders == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num_folders; i++) {
        snprintf(chrome_path_login_db, sizeof(chrome_path_login_db),
                 "%s\\%s\\Login Data", chrome_path, folders[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num_folders; i++) {
        free(folders[i]);
    }
    free(folders);


    // Move the database and use the SQLite 3 library to open the file.
    FILE *fptr1, *fptr2;
    char temp_vault[100];
    char buffer[1024];
    size_t bytes_read;

    fptr1 = fopen(chrome_path_login_db, "rb");
    if (fptr1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file %s \n", chrome_path_login_db);
        exit(0);
    }

    sprintf(temp_vault, "%s\\vault.db", temp_path);
    fptr2 = fopen(temp_vault, "wb");
    if (fptr2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file %s \n", temp_vault);
        exit(0);
    }

    while ((bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fptr1)) > 0)
    {
        fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, fptr2);
    }

    fclose(fptr1);
    fclose(fptr2);
    sqlite3* db = main_sqlite_password_dumper(temp_vault);
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting to get the passwords like it should, like I did last year.

Comment: You can't mix OpenSSL headers with `wincrypt.h`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504648/x509-name-macro-in-c-wont-compile

Comment: @AndrewHenle Hello, I know, I tried to remove it, but it is used in the program so it won't work. I can't seem to find out a solution, might be in the order of my includes.

Comment: There's a symbol collision over the `X509_NAME` symbol between OpenSSL and `wincrypt,h`.  You **can't** mix the two, in any order.  You need to split your program into multiple files to avoid the collision over the symbol.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I understand what you're trying to say, but **I did get it to work** last year, I did nothing different, I just remember the arguments in my gcc were longer and there was many.